# Issue regarding char datatype in c++

Tags: c++

I understand the fact that 'char' datatype is used to store single character and uses 1 byte but what are char16_t, char32_t, and wchar_t used for? We, after all, have to store just a single character only

Comment: What if your alphabet has more than 256 characters?

Comment: They are used to store unicode characters typically.
While utf8 can use single byte characters utf16 and utf32 require more bytes.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this but an alphabet is 1 character wide only I assume? How can it be 256 characters wide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `char16_t` and `char32_t`, quoting from a [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/char-wchar-t-char16-t-char32-t?view=vs-2019):

> The char16_t and char32_t types represent 16-bit and 32-bit wide characters, respectively. Unicode encoded as UTF-16 can be stored in the char16_t type, and Unicode encoded as UTF-32 can be stored in the char32_t type. Strings of these types and wchar_t are all referred to as wide strings, though the term often refers specifically to strings of wchar_t type.

And for `wchar_t`:

> The wchar_t type is an implementation-defined wide character type. In the Microsoft compiler, it represents a 16-bit wide character used to store Unicode encoded as UTF-16LE, the native character type on Windows operating systems. The wide character versions of the Universal C Runtime (UCRT) library functions use wchar_t and its pointer and array types as parameters and return values, as do the wide character versions of the native Windows API.

So they can't be said as simply a character. The type differs with the encoding, as mentioned above.

For example, the character `u` (U+0075) in `char16_t` encoding is stored as `feff0075`.

Comment: Re: "For example, The character u in char16_t encoding is stored as byte feff0075 (U+0075)" -- not quite. That's the **UTF-16** representation of that character. It can be stored in a `char16_t`, but `char16_t` is not restricted to UTF-16 (just as `char` is not restricted to ASCII, even though many people think they are the same). You **always** have to know what encoding is being used.

Comment: `u` is stored in a single `char16_t` as just `0x0075`. `0xfeff` represents the UTF-16 [BOM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and would be in a separate `char16_t` if present at all.